# How do I find $F(r(t))$ for the work done over line integrals?

Tags: linear-algebra

I don't know what this notations means what does $$ F(r(t)) $$ mean ? Are they asking me to find the force in terms of $r(t)$ ? The force vector just has $xs$ and $ys$ in it ?

How is it treated when if the i component for example has both an $x$ and a $y$ ? for example

$$x^2y^2i $$

Answer (score 1):

You are given a force field ${\bf F}$ in three space, say. This means that at each point ${\bf r}\in{\mathbb R}^3$ a force vector ${\bf F}({\bf r})=\bigl(F_1(x,y,z), F_2(x,y,z),F_3(x,y,z)\bigr)$ is attached. In general this force vector changes from point to point, i.e., it is a function of ${\bf r}$.

In addition you are given a curve
$$\gamma:\quad t\mapsto{\bf r}(t)=\bigl(x(t),y(t),z(t)\bigr)\qquad(a\leq t\leq b)$$
in three-space. For each individual $t\in[a,b]$ the value ${\bf r}(t)$ is a certain point on this curve, and ${\bf F}\bigl({\bf r}(t)\bigr)$, obtained by plugging in the parametric representation $t\mapsto {\bf r}(t)$ of $\gamma$  into ${\bf F}$, is the force vector attached to this point.

When a particle moves along $\gamma$ under the influence of this force field  without taking up speed, or when you have to push a chart along $\gamma$ against the force field, then the total work done is given by the line integral
$$W=\int_\gamma {\bf F}\cdot d{\bf r}:=\int_a^b{\bf F}\bigl({\bf r}(t)\bigr)\cdot\dot{\bf r}(t)\ dt\ ,$$
as is explained in physics courses.